# Javascript/json keep in database and special chars

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, immutable.js

I have layout builder in React to keep data structure and text I use ImmutableJS objects.

Such structure with attributes as text or css styles is saved into database as JSON.

To make it JSON I using json-immutable library: serialize, deserialize functions.

After save in database I provide configuration for react components as javascript variables. For example my backend generate js file with variables or small part is printing directly in html code using `script` tag.

Data are JSON or decoded javascript.

The biggest problem I have with save special chars.

For example if someone set `'` single quote in some attribute it is saved directly.
But when I print it in html code as

```
var myConfig = '{anyjson}';
```

when inside JSON is single quote parser throw error. The same with double quotes, `&` (ampersant) or any chars used in html code like `<,/>`

Single quote I replace to \' when I print it in html code.

But I think does exists any way to save keep all data in JSON and still they will easy to decode by deserialize function to parse JSON to ImmutableJS objects.

Code example
https://jsfiddle.net/jaroapp/2yzud6ua/2/

```
var structure = {
   "__iterable":"Map",
   "data":[
      [
         "entityMap",
         {
            "__iterable":"Map",
            "data":[
               [
                  "html_el_qb7tyhi",
                  {
                     "__iterable":"Map",
                     "data":[
                        [
                           "imported",
                           false
                        ],
                        [
                           "path",
                           "html_el_qb7tyhi"
                        ],
                        [
                           "componentData",
                           {
                              "__iterable":"Map",
                              "data":[

                              ]
                           }
                        ],
                        [
                           "draftjsObject",
                           {
                              "__iterable":"OrderedMap",
                              "data":[

                              ]
                           }
                        ],
                        [
                           "draftjs",
                           true
                        ],
                        [
                           "data",
                           {
                              "__iterable":"OrderedMap",
                              "data":[
                                 [
                                    "text",
                                    "B&B is the best company. It's my hope for new markets."
                                 ]
                              ]
                           }
                        ],
                        [
                           "chunk",
                           null
                        ],
                        [
                           "style",
                           {
                              "__iterable":"OrderedMap",
                              "data":[
                                 [
                                    "background-image",
                                    "url(\"/path/to/image.jpg\")"
                                 ]
                              ]
                           }
                        ],
                        [
                           "attr",
                           {
                              "__iterable":"OrderedMap",
                              "data":[

                              ]
                           }
                        ],
                        [
                           "runEditor",
                           false
                        ],
                        [
                           "entityMap",
                           {
                              "__iterable":"OrderedMap",
                              "data":[

                              ]
                           }
                        ],
                        [
                           "type",
                           "div"
                        ],
                        [
                           "key",
                           "html_el_qb7tyhi"
                        ]
                     ]
                  }
               ],
               [
                  "html_el_2dgupn7",
                  {
                     "__iterable":"Map",
                     "data":[
                        [
                           "imported",
                           false
                        ],
                        [
                           "path",
                           "html_el_2dgupn7"
                        ],
                        [
                           "componentData",
                           {
                              "__iterable":"Map",
                              "data":[

                              ]
                           }
                        ],
                        [
                           "draftjsObject",
                           {
                              "entityMap":{

                              },
                              "blocks":[
                                 {
                                    "key":"3ia22",
                                    "text":"Text saved with html inside",
                                    "type":"unstyled",
                                    "depth":0,
                                    "inlineStyleRanges":[

                                    ],
                                    "entityRanges":[

                                    ],
                                    "data":{

                                    }
                                 }
                              ]
                           }
                        ],
                        [
                           "draftjs",
                           true
                        ],
                        [
                           "data",
                           {
                              "__iterable":"OrderedMap",
                              "data":[
                                 [
                                    "text",
                                    null
                                 ],
                                 [
                                    "html",
                                    "<p class=\"md-block-unstyled\">Text saved with html inside</p>"
                                 ]
                              ]
                           }
                        ],
                        [
                           "chunk",
                           null
                        ],
                        [
                           "style",
                           {
                              "__iterable":"OrderedMap",
                              "data":[

                              ]
                           }
                        ],
                        [
                           "attr",
                           {
                              "__iterable":"OrderedMap",
                              "data":[

                              ]
                           }
                        ],
                        [
                           "runEditor",
                           false
                        ],
                        [
                           "entityMap",
                           {
                              "__iterable":"OrderedMap",
                              "data":[

                              ]
                           }
                        ],
                        [
                           "type",
                           "div"
                        ],
                        [
                           "key",
                           "html_el_2dgupn7"
                        ]
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            ]
         }
      ],
      [
         "containersMap",
         {
            "__iterable":"Map",
            "data":[

            ]
         }
      ],
      [
         "componentsMap",
         {
            "__iterable":"Map",
            "data":[
               [
                  "entityMap",
                  {
                     "__iterable":"OrderedMap",
                     "data":[

                     ]
                  }
               ]
            ]
         }
      ]
   ]
};
```

Such structure I set as parameter into ReactJS component.

If I set it as JSON and wrap in quotes then the browser throws an error. If I set it as JavaScript object into the React component I can't make ImmutableJS from this one, because this structure is read by this
https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-immutable library (I use the same to make JSON from Immutable JS to save it in database);

Thanks in advance for any hints.

Comment: Just don't wrap the JSON in quotes. Except for some rare boundary cases, you can just inject JSON in JavaScript, and it will read it as a JavaScript object literal.

Comment: it should solve problem with single quote but not with double quotes or `&` or I'm wrong?

Comment: As long as this occurs in a JavaScript script context, you can of course have `&` and `"` in there. Can you show an example where it does not work?

Comment: I edited question and aded. It's only little part because JSON lis longer.

Comment: this is only part. All is really long and have sensitive data. Yes as first is {}. I'd like show you how it save chars what throw errors.

Comment: There is no problem when you put that JSON as-is (without wrapping in quotes to make it a string) in the JavaScript assignment. See it here: https://jsfiddle.net/gnnr9cn8/

Comment: hmm, thanks. I have to check in all places in my code and back here if I'll more information. Thanks.

Comment: hmm, but what will happen if I'll set it to `deserialize` or `JSON.parse` function? I will throw error because it isn't string. I need to use deserialize because I need to ImmutableJS object instead object with arrays what I have in JSON

Comment: That makes the question quite larger. Please edit your question to add all these elements, and include sample data for both those JSON-serialised arrays and main data, how they need to be combined, and how you make them immutable with ImmutableJS.

Comment: I edited question. Shared example JSON structure and shared library what I use to convert ImmutableJS=>JSON and JSON=>ImmutableJS. 
I can't attach this library to jsfiddle this is reason why I don't shared working/not working example. My problem is to make ImmutableJS object from this not only import without errors.

Comment: People with expertise in react should look at this. To get them here, I tagged your question with `react` and `immutablejs`. Still, you should add the relevant code: snippets of your code where you call immutable methods (or would like to), and the code where you define your component.

Comment: Thanks. I updated code. Added example component in jsfiddle

Comment: I didn't test in all cases but it looks that I solve problem. 
I copied function deserialize from json-immutable library. Added to own app with modification which check source type. If is not string skip JSON.parse. Will make more tests because I use it many times but It looks really promising. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Good to hear you found a solution. Once you are confident, you should enter a proper answer: it is OK on StackOverflow to answer your own questions.

Comment: I added but I can accept it in 2 days. it says me stacoverflow

Comment: Ah, didn't know that. There is always something new to learn here :-)

Comment: every day is school day :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem. Short description, maybe will helpful for someone.

I get file with deserialize function form json-immutable package. And I modified function deserialize to

```
export function deserialize(json){
  var options = arguments.length > 1 && arguments[1] !== undefined ? arguments[1] : {};
  if(typeof json==='string'){
    return JSON.parse(json, function(key, value, options){
      return revive(key, value, options);
    });
  }else{
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(json), function(key, value, options){
      return revive(key, value, options);
    });
  }
}
```

Function in package use JSON.parse for param. Maybe it's not the most elegant solution but I don't have time to find way to don't "re-json" object. Standard `Object.keys` and `map` return origin object.